# How to integrate gpt such that it gets context from pdf as well as also provide generic answers

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

This is how my current code looks like

```
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)

retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3,'include_metadata': True})

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
        "The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and "
        "provides lots of specific details from its context. If the AI does not know the answer to a "
        "question, it truthfully says it does not know."
    ),
    MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{input}")
])



llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(llm=llm,memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True, output_key='answer')

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=retriever, memory=memory)

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a query: ")
    if user_input == "exit":
        break

    query = f"###Prompt {user_input}"
    try:
        llm_response = qa({"question": query})
        print(llm_response['answer'])


    except Exception as err:
        print('Exception occurred. Please try again', str(err))
```

This gets me the answer from the pdf that I have embedded but does not answer Generic questions like "who is the prime minister of India"

How could I integrate both of them working at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify you prompt as below

```
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
            "The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and "
            "provides lots of specific details from its context. If the AI does not know the answer to a "
            "question, you can provide generic answer to the query."
        ),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{input}")
    ])
```

Comment: This is does not work, I asked it, who was the captain of indian cricket team and it replied "I don't know", any oher prompt that we can give ?